# how to write a bash script to make directory using first positional parameter? and create file on second positional parameter

Tags: bash, ubuntu

i am writing a bash script to make directory using first positional parameter, move into the directory, and create a file in it using second positional parameter. I couldnt move into the directory. it creates the directory and file separately. Any help how to fix it please.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n what direcory?
read base
mkdir -p "$base"
echo -n what file?
read file
```

Comment: show your code so people will understand the context of your problem better

Comment: Please provide the code of your attempt as well.

Comment: Share your code and the error that you're facing so people can reproduce

Comment: Share your code and the error that you're facing so people can reproduce

Comment: this is what i was trying to do.#!/bin/bash
echo -n what direcory?
read base
mkdir -p "$base"

echo -n what file?
read file

Comment: @ela I've attempted to add your code to the question, but it looks incomplete (i.e. it's missing anything to create the file); please edit the question to correct it (indent 4 spaces for code format). BTW, it looks like your script is reading the dir and file from standard input rather than taking them as parameters; is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p "$1"
touch "$1/$2"
```

USAGE: `create.sh /tmp/my/special/dir myfile`